# SeachView in API8

Tags: android, api, searchview

When I have put SearchView into activity_main.xml

```
<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</SearchView>
```

It is giving error:

> View requires API level 11(current min is 8)

Is there any way to support SearchView in API8?

PS. When I had same problem with SimpleCursorAdapter, I have solved by this:

> import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) or the new [AppCompat-v7](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) **(recommended for new projects)** library.

Add either library to your project (make sure to follow the *Adding libraries with resources* section if using AppCompat), then use:

`import com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView;`

or:

`import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;`

respectively.

Comment: When I use import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView; should I add ActionBarSherlock library?

Comment: No, just the AppCompat library.

Comment: What to do in steps in 2 and 3? They say:"In the Library pane, click Add.
Select the library project and click OK. For example, the appcompat project should be listed as android-support-v7-appcompat." There are changes there. For example: there is no library tab and "add" button. Added screenshot of my screen above.

Comment: Have you tried "Add library..."? I don't use Eclipse, so I can't help you there I'm afraid.

Comment: Is it possible to support just SearchView (without ActionBar) in API8?

Comment: You can't use SearchView without an ActionBar compatibility library (such as ActionBarSherlock or AppCompat).