# Just SearchView in API8(without ActionBar)

Tags: android, api, searchview

I know how to implement SearchView with [appcombat-v7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18444753/2255924) ActionBar. How to implement just SearchView without ActionBar in API8?

```
    <SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</SearchView>
```

Is it possible to support SearchView in API8?